# How to map this legacy table with NHibernate (Fluent)?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, mapping, hierarchy, legacy

New to NHibernate.  Having trouble wrapping my head around how to map this legacy table.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CmnAddress](
[addressId] [int] NOT NULL,
[objectType] [varchar](63) NULL,
[objectId] [int] NULL,
[addressType] [varchar](7) NULL,
[recordStatus] [char](1) NULL,
[fromDate] [int] NULL,
[toDate] [int] NULL,
[onStreet] [varchar](254) NULL,
[atStreet] [varchar](254) NULL,
[unit] [varchar](30) NULL,
[city] [varchar](254) NULL,
[state] [varchar](30) NULL,
[zipCode] [varchar](30) NULL,
)
```

There is also a "CmnPerson" table that I have mapped to a Person class.  I need the Person class to contain a list of Addresses, where the objectType column contains "CmnPerson" and the objectId field matches my Person.Id ("CmnPerson.personId") field.

I am also later going to have to create a Contact class that also contains a list of Addresses where the objectType column contains "CmnContact".

I'm having a very tough time figuring out if I should be using the Any mapping or class-hierarchy-per-table with discrimination on subcolumns?  Or if either of those will even meet my needs.

Can anyone show my how to map this Address class?  Fluent config would be preferable.

**ADDED INFO:**

The following classes and mappings almost work, but the Addresses list return ALL rows from the CmnAddress table with a matching objectId, regardless of the objectType field's value.  I think I could use an ApplyFilter on the HasMany mapping for Person.Addresses, but that doesn't seem like the "right" way.

**More added info:** I was able to resolve this last issue by chaining AlwaysSelectWithValue() on after the call to DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn(...)

```
public class Person
{
    public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public virtual string Gender { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<PassClient> PassClients { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<PersonAddress> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public class PersonMap : ClassMap<Person>
{
    public PersonMap() {
        Table("CmnPerson");
        Id(x => x.Id).Column("personId");
        Map(x => x.LastName);
        Map(x => x.FirstName);
        Map(x => x.MiddleName);
        Map(x => x.Gender);

        HasMany(x => x.PassClients).KeyColumn("personId");
        HasMany(x => x.Addresses).KeyColumn("objectId");
    }
}

abstract public class Address
{
    public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
    public virtual string StreetNo { get; set; }
    public virtual string OnStreet { get; set; }
    public virtual string Unit { get; set; }
    public virtual string City { get; set; }
    public virtual string State { get; set; }
    public virtual string ZipCode { get; set; }
}

public class PersonAddress : Address { 
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}

public class AddressMap : ClassMap<Address>
{
    public AddressMap() {
        Table("CmnAddress");

        Id(x => x.Id).Column("addressId");
        Map(x => x.StreetNo);
        Map(x => x.OnStreet);
        Map(x => x.Unit);
        Map(x => x.City);
        Map(x => x.State);
        Map(x => x.ZipCode);

        DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("objectType").AlwaysSelectWithValue();
    }
}

public class PersonAddressMap : SubclassMap<PersonAddress>
{
  public PersonAddressMap() {
        DiscriminatorValue("CmnPerson");

        References(x => x.Person).Column("objectId");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use the Any-mapping when it's a has many relation. It can be used, when an address can point to different kinds of objects - like a person, an order or other things not related.

To map the hierarachy you can do it like this:

```
public class CmnAddressMap : ClassMap<CmnAddress>
{
    public CmnAddressMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.addressId);
        Map(x => x...);

        DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("objectType");
    }
}

public class PersonAdressMap : SubclassMap<PersonAddress>
{
    public PersonAdressMap()
    {
        DiscriminatorValue("objectType1");
    }
}

public class ContactAdressMap : SubclassMap<ContactAddress>
{
    public ContactAdressMap()
    {
        DiscriminatorValue("objectType2");
    }
}
```

Have an abstract CmnAddress with all the fields (map all the fields in the CmnAdressMap for example) and two subclasses named PersonAddress and ContactAddress.

And the person should then have a collection like IList which should mapped with HasMany. And you should be done.

Comment: I came to this exact same answer just now - just finished testing it.

It does compile and run, but the Person.Addresses list returns ALL rows from the CmnAddress table with a matching id value, regardless of the value in the discriminating column.

Any ideas on how to resolve that?

Comment: To which the answer is to chain the AlwaysSelectWithValue() call after the DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn(...) call.  Or at least it seems to have the desired result.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. That's pretty strange. I just ran a test with your scenario, and there is no need for me to specify AlwaysSelectWithValue().

Comment: Oh. Now I see your new info. Have you any rows in the adresses table, that has no discriminator or a discriminator value that is not mapped to subclass?

Comment: I do in fact have discriminator values that are not mapped to subclasses, which is the reason I have to specifiy AlwaysSelectWithValue().

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, am not familiar with fluent mappings, however, one way to do it would be:

- Create an **Address** abstract class with properties corresponding to all the columns in your table except for **objectType**
- Create a **PersonAddress** class which extends **Address**
- Create a **ContactAddress** class which extends **Address**
- Map all the columns of *CmnAddress* to properties of the **Address** class in the normal way, except for **objectType** which you declare as the discriminator column
- Map **PersonAddress** as a subclass of **Address** with discriminator value "CmnPerson"
- Map **ContactAddress** as a subclass of **Address** with a discriminator value of "CmnContact"

In code, your Person class would hold a list of **PersonAddresses** and your Contact class would hold a list of **ContactAddresses**

Answer (score 0):

Address class

```
public class Address
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
    // etc.
}
```

Person class

```
public class Person
{
    public Person()
    {
        Addresses = new List<Address>();
    }

    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    // etc.
    public virtual IList<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}
```

AddressMap

```
public class AddressMap : ClassMap<Address>
{
    public AddressMap()
    {
        Table("CmnAddress");
        Id(x => x.Id).Column("addressId");
        // etc.
        References(x => x.Person);
    }
}
```

To separate the difference between Address => Person and Address => Contact, you'll want to read up on NHibernate's polymorphism and discriminate sub classes based on column.

Comment: Its the discriminate part I am having trouble understanding.

I'm not sure if I need to make subclasses that inherit from Address - like PersonsAddress & ContactsAddress.  I also wasn't entirely clear on the Fluent method of mapping the string vaules "CmnPerson" & "CmnContact" to the appropriate Address subclasses.